# How do I install Audiere?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to install PyAudiere (on MacOS 10.5), and it needs Audiere installed. I downloaded the Unix source from the Audiere website and ran configure and the makefile. I also tried adding audiere.h to the g++ include path with the command:

```
g++ -I /[...]/audiere-1.9.4/src audiere.h.
```

This did *something*, but I'm not sure what. When I try to install PyAudiere using

```
python setup.py install
```

it always says

> error: audiere.h: No such file or directory.

Have I installed Audiere? If not, how do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried both `#include "audiere.h"` and `#include <audiere.h>`?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I know virtually nothing about mac OS

If you have run configure:

> ./configure

and the makefile:

> make

Have you then run:

> make install

Without running `make install` you have simply compiled the files but not installed them into your system.  Under linux you might have to run `sudo make install` in order to get the administrative privileges required to install files.